# samba share as download location for firefox (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, mount, firefox, samba

I want to download something using firefox to a network share on a synology nas (with password security). 
In the file browser I can acces the share (but I cannot write to it because it is mounted read only?). But the download to window in firefox does not list network shares...So I tried to mount the share to /mnt/nas using smbmount and mount.cifs.

```
sudo smbmount //192.168.2.20/software /mnt/nas -o user=the_user file_mode=0777,  dir_mode=0777, dmask=777, fmask=777,umask=022 rw 0 0
```

This works and I can create folders. But when I point Firefox to it can't write to it..how should I mount the share as a download location for Firefox?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Nautilus and command line can write to the mounts, but Firefox and other apps can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug with GTK, that has now been patched:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586367

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/697440

I'm not sure which version of gtk you're on, but maybe updating will fix the issue, though you may need to update Ubuntu to something more recent than 12.04.

Comment: Ok, 14.04 should sort it for you then. For info, I've just updated from 12.04 to 13.10 and the issue is fixed.